# Calculating average speed from columns that have both a distance and a time (NULL issues)

Tags: sql, mysql, null

I have two columns in a MySQL database.  One is a distance column, and the other is a time column.  In some cases one or both of these values is not known, and thus, NULL.  I want to create a query that finds the average speed, excluding any null entries.

For instance:

```
Distance    Time

60          60
120         60
NULL        45
30          NULL
NULL        NULL
```

The computed average speed should be `(60+120)/(60+60) = 1.5`

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aggregate over the rows where both values are not NULL:

```
SELECT SUM(Distance)/SUM(Time) AS AvgSpeed
FROM yourtable
WHERE Distance IS NOT NULL
AND Time IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Works great!  Thanks.  Would you happen to know any good resources that teach writing SQL queries to do these sorts of things?

Comment: @Nick: You could try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982/looking-for-a-good-book-to-learn-sql